# Pass a Variable in Function in an addEventListener

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

How do I pass one variable on the function `previewImages`?

```js
document.querySelector('#file-input0').addEventListener("change", previewImages,false);
document.querySelector('#file-input1').addEventListener("change", previewImages,false);
```

I want this script to call the function:

```js
function previewImages(i){
        var preview = document.getElementById("preview"+i);
        if (this.files) {
          [].forEach.call(this.files, readAndPreview);
        }}
```

Everytime I tried this I cant achieve passing the variable value. I want to implement this in pure javascript.

Comment: Do you mean passing the variable value to `document.querySelector...` ?

Comment: No. I mean like setting a variable in the document.querySelector... and pass it to the function previewImages()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare a function directly as a handler and call the function `previewImages` from inside of it.

```
document.querySelector('#file-input0').addEventListener("change", function() {
  previewImages(0);
}, false);

document.querySelector('#file-input1').addEventListener("change", function() {
  previewImages(1);
}, false);
```

Comment: @ErlV can you explain, why this didn't work?

Comment: IT WORKS. I tried displaying the value in an alert and it indeed passes the value. Great thanks.